# Can I say "over-exceed"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Let's say there's an accepted price range for rent. I would like to charge rent fairly, but I'm renting to a very wealthly individual. I don't mind exceeding the accepted range in my asking price, but I don't want to exaggerate and **over-exceed.**

Is this usage correct? In my searched I didn't find this phrase used. I don't think this is a pleonasm, because there are different levels in the excession, as I described above.

**Edit**:

I want something formal that I'll feel comfortable using in a user guide.  I want it to sound professional.

Comment: I would argue that anyone who answers "no" is being rather prescriptivist. If the you use the word and it puts the idea that you want to convey into another person's head, then I would say that is successful communication.

Comment: @mattliu If I were putting it in a written letter (unlikely), I would certainly have it in quotation marks.

Comment: My instinct is that it's tautology (saying the same thing twice). Better to say 'exceed by too much'.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm renting to a very wealthy individual. I don't mind exceeding the accepted range in my asking price, but I don't want to overdo it.

***[overdo it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/overdo+it)***: to do too much of something.  *There are always some students at parties who overdo it.*

(What it is that might be overdone has to be figured out from the context.)

Comment: this is a good answer but i fear its a bit too informal. I want something i'll feel comfortable using in a user guide that will sound professional.

Comment: @DAE - It's helpful to clarify your needs as to the tone, as you did; so I added this to the question. // overextend, overinflate, overstretch, overamplify.

Answer (score 1):

While `over-exceed` could still be used, `over-shoot` or `over-shot` could be used as a better fit alternative.
Hope this helps.